# Request burnination of [toggleclass]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I just happened across the tag [toggleclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toggleclass) in my daily perusing of JavaScript questions. The tag description indicates that it is used to mark the `jQuery.toggleClass` method.

I believe this tag should be destroyed because it is simply clutter. There is no value I can see in having a tag dedicated to a single function. My proposal would be that all questions tagged [toggleclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toggleclass) be tagged with [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) (if they are not already) and have [toggleclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toggleclass) removed.

Comment: Interesting that there is a non negligable amount of question tagged toggleclass, [without both jquery and javascript tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toggleclass+-jquery+-javascript). This would be a reason to me why the tag is harmful: it can make some users post questions that are just completely ignored (because no-one really follows toggleclass).

Comment: Take a look at ["burnination"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/215552) which is the made-up word we use when talking about removing tags.

Comment: Thank you @MikeMcCaughan. My Google-fu wasn't up to the task of discovering that piece of vocabulary :) I've rewritten the question to be a burnination request for [tag:toggleclass] rather than a question of how to handle worthless tags.

Comment: "Toggle [toggleclass]" for suggested title.

Comment: The fastest way to deal with this is to make this tag a synonym of [tag:jquery], just like [tag:addclass].

Comment: @approxiblue That's a good idea, but I lack the required 2,500 reputation.

Comment: I'm hoping a moderator will pass by and help us. I can't suggest any synonym for [tag:toggleclass] because it's being suggested as a synonym for [tag:removeclass], which should also be burninated.

Comment: Ohmigosh my question is a HOT META POST! I'm famous! I'd like to thank my mother...

Comment: @approxiblue why would you want to synonym soon-to-be-burninated tags?

Comment: @Braiam Because burninating [tag:toggleclass] questions more or less means retagging them all with [tag:jquery].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While trying to make [toggleclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toggleclass) a synonym of [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), I was informed that someone else had proposed [toggleclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toggleclass) as a synonym of [removeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/removeclass).

I'm not going to speculate on what thought process went into making that suggestion, but I deleted that suggestion and made *both* tags synonyms of [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

At long last, [addclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addclass), [removeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/removeclass) and [toggleclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toggleclass) have been reunited as one.

<sub>I should think about getting that gold [jquery-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-selectors) badge sometime soon...</sub>

Comment: Wait, so you just made all the tags synonyms of [jquery]? The day has finally come.